# Mapping @OneToOne with @Where clause

Tags: hibernate, where-clause, one-to-one

I am trying to map an entity as following

```
@OneToOne(mappedBy = "localizedLabel")
@JoinColumn(insertable = false, updatable = false)
@WhereJoinTable(clause = "locale='en_US'")
public Localization getEn_US() {
    return en_US;
}
```

I can assure that the data will return only one or null if the not found, but hibernate seems to ignore my @Where clause:

```
ERROR com.eventtouch.bc.business.core.log.LoggingInterceptor - org.hibernate.HibernateException: More than one row with the given identifier was found: 4211, for class: com.eventtouch.bc.business.domain.LocalizedLabel
```

Any ideas on ho to map a @OneToOne relationship with @Where clause?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your @OneToOne does not seem to use a join table.

In that case, shouldn't you use a @Where annotation rather than the @WhereJoinTable that filters rows of a join table ?

Answer (score 0):

When you use `@JoinColumn` reference column is created in source table (as it is one to one association) this avoid creating a join table.